# Setting up online payment

Tags: javascript, node.js

Need help creating a payment on the site, using paytrail.

I'm a little confused in reading the documentation and I can't figure out how to do what seems to be such a simple task.

first I send a request to the server to get the hash and confirm my request to the paytrail server with it.

after I send a request from the frontend to the paytrail server to create an order.

how to implement request?

can you please give me a code example that would make it easier for me to understand how it should work.

documentation: https://docs.paytrail.com/#/?id=test-credentials

node.js - server:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const ACCOUNT = '375917';
const SECRET = 'SAIPPUAKAUPPIAS';

const calculateHmac = (secret, params, body) => {
const hmacPayload = Object.keys(params)
.sort()
.map((key) => [key, params[key]].join(':'))
.concat(body ? JSON.stringify(body) : '')
.join('\n');

return crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret).update(hmacPayload).digest('hex');
};

const headers = {
'checkout-account': ACCOUNT,
'checkout-algorithm': 'sha256',
'checkout-method': 'POST',
'checkout-nonce': '564635208570151',
'checkout-timestamp': '2023-07-06T10:01:31.904Z',
};

const body = {
stamp: 'unique-identifier-for-merchant',
reference: '3759170',
amount: 1525,
currency: 'EUR',
language: 'FI',
items: [
{
unitPrice: 1525,
units: 1,
vatPercentage: 24,
productCode: '#1234',
deliveryDate: '2023-09-01',
},
],
customer: {
email: 'test.customer@example.com',
},
redirectUrls: {
success: 'http://localhost:8080/web/cart',
cancel: 'http://localhost:8080/web/cart',
},
};

const http = require("http");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
res.end(JSON.stringify({
hash: await calculateHmac(SECRET, headers, body)
}));
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`server started on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

fontend:

```
    <template>
<div>
<button @click="createPayment">create payment</button>
</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import axios from 'axios'

const createPayment = () => {
axios.post('https://services.paytrail.com/', {
orderNumber: '12345',
amount: 100.00,
currency: 'EUR',
locale: 'fi_FI',
returnUrl: 'https://project.su/web/',
cancelUrl: 'https://project.su/web/',
notificationUrl: 'https://project.su/web/'
}, {
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
'checkout-account': '375917',
'checkout-algorithm': 'sha256',
'checkout-method': 'POST',
'checkout-nonce': 'server hash',
'checkout-timestamp': '2023-07-06T10:01:31.904Z',
},
})
.then(response => {

console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(error => {

console.error(error);
});
}
</script>
```